# JSON processing with jq -- how to do complex awk-like output formatting?

Tags: json, bash, shell, awk, jq

I have the following JSON object:

```json
{
  "attacks": {
    "normal fist": {
      "type": "melee",
      "damage": 3
    },
    "thunder fist": {
      "type": "melee",
      "damage": 5,
      "attributes": [
        "electrical"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `jq`, I want to print the following to standard output:

```
  attacks:
  - name: normal fist
    type: melee
    damage: 3
  - name: thunder fist
    damage: 5
    attributes:
      electrical
```

This short script does most of what I want:

```
jq -r '.attacks | to_entries | .[] |
    { 
        "- name":.key,
        "  type":.value.Type, 
        "  damage":.value.Number,
    }' | awk -F: '/  "/ { gsub(/^  /,""); gsub(/"/,""); print $0 }'
```

There are two problems I am facing.

#1 - I only want the "attributes" key to be printed under the "thunder fist" entry. I can't figure out how to make the printing of that portion conditional.

#2 - I can't figure out how to format the nested object "attributes."

I can't find much in the `jq` documentation on formatting output. I'm trying to treat `jq` as a JSON-specific `awk` -- is this even possible?

Comment: If you only want the “attributes” key under “thunder fist”, why have you included “damage”?

Answer (score 2):

jq is Turing-complete, so if your format is well-defined, it would be possible to use jq to perform the transformation.  But rather than inventing a new format, why not consider YAML:

```
$ gojq --yaml-output . attacks.json
attacks:
  normal fist:
    damage: 3
    type: melee
  thunder fist:
    attributes:
      - electrical
    damage: 5
    type: melee
```

If you really need the "-name:" prefix as shown, you could perhaps post-process the above, e.g.:

```
$ gojq --yaml-output . attacks.json | sed '/^  [^ ].*:$/ {s/  /  - name: /; s/:$//;}'
attacks:
  - name: normal fist
    damage: 3
    type: melee
  - name: thunder fist
    attributes:
      - electrical
    damage: 5
    type: melee
```

Answer (score 2):

Except for the unclear rquirement #1, which can be handled via some jq preprocessing, the following does the job in this particular case, but might need fortifying for more genericity:

```
def indentArray(indent):
  (indent * " ") as $i
  | .[] | "\($i)\(.)";

def simplekv(indent):
  (indent * " ") as $i
  | keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | if .[$k] | type == "array"
    then "\($i)\($k):", (.[$k] | indentArray(indent+2))
    else "\($i)\($k): \(.[$k])"
    end;
    
keys_unsorted[] as $k
| ($k + ":"),
  (.[$k] as $o
  | ($o|keys_unsorted[]) as $k1
  | ("-name: " + $k1), ($o[$k1] | simplekv(2)) )
```

#### Output

```
attacks:
-name: normal fist
  type: melee
  damage: 3
-name: thunder fist
  type: melee
  damage: 5
  attributes:
    electrical
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach going down the YAML route would be to use the YAML processor (e.g. [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), ...) itself for pre-processing.

Here is an example using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '.[] |= (to_entries | map({name: .key} + .value))' attacks.json
```

```yaml
attacks:
  - name: normal fist
    type: melee
    damage: 3
  - name: thunder fist
    type: melee
    damage: 5
    attributes:
      - electrical
```

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the "attributes" key to be printed under the "thunder
> fist" entry. I can't figure out how to make the printing of that
> portion conditional.

Then take look at `if A then B else C end` statement, consider following simple example, let input for jq command be

```
[{"attack":"A"},{"attack":"B","attributes":["C"]}]
```

then

```
jq -r '.[] | .attack + if .attributes then .attributes[] else "" end'
```

gives output

```
A
BC
```

Explanation: this construct is equivalent to ternary operator *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse* as found in GNU AWK and Javascript, above use `.attributes[]` if `.attributes` is truthy empty string otherwise, consult [Conditionals and Comparisons section of manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons) to learn more about it.